# On Windows 10, I cannot two-finger-scroll in Google Inbox with Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, touchpad, scrolling, inbox

I have a Dell XPS 13 (2015) which I just upgraded to Windows 10. I can no longer scroll using two-finger drag on the touchpad when in Google Inbox, using Chrome 45.0.2454.15. I can still scroll using the scroll bar on the right, and my touch screen.

This goes for reading individual emails, viewing the entire list, and my chat contacts on the right.

I don't seem to have the issue on other websites.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try entering **chrome://flags** in your adress bar, searching for **Enable touch events** and setting that dropdown to **Disabled**. Recent versions of  chrome do strange things on some pages that rely on detecting touch capabilities. Honestly I don't know why, but disabling touch events usually fixes the issue. You'll be left without touch support though, which may or may not be a dealbreaker for you.

Comment: You're right - that fixed it. And I have lost touch support entirely for Chrome. Hmm, this is a shame, but it did fix my problem I suppose.

Comment: There has to be a better option than this...

Comment: 2 years later, there's no longer an "Enable touch events" flag, but a "Touch events API" flag set to automatic. I set it to enabled and relaunched Chrome and Slack and I was able to scroll!