# Can't two-finger or touch scroll in Chrome after resuming from suspend

Tags: windows-10, google-chrome, touchpad, scrolling

I have a Dell Inspiron 2-in-1 laptop running Windows 10 that recently has developed the problem where my two-finger and touch scrolling in Chrome just up and quits every time my computer has been suspended.  I'm fairly certain that it's the suspending that is doing it, but it could be just happening after a certain amount of time (I always notice it after it has gone to sleep on it's own).

Restarting Chrome fixes it, but other fixes like what is [suggested here](https://superuser.com/q/948531/118184) do not.  Scrolling with scrollbars continues to work, and this doesn't happen in any other program I use.  I'm not sure exactly how long this has been happening, but it might have been since my laptop got the Windows 10 Anniversary Update (v1607).

One other weird thing with this is that Chrome has to be shut down completely in order to restore proper scrolling.  Closing one window if others are open does not fix it, neither does launching a new window.

Answer (score -1):

The same thing has happened to me on my Surface Pro 4 after the Windows anniversary update. Pretty annoying. I'd love a fix.

Do you have Kaspersky? It sounds like this is the cause:
https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=647038#

I have it too.

Comment: Since you have the same problem, how is it solved?  Provide specifics

Comment: Welcome to Super User! On this Q&A site we try to provide [good answers](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-answer) to questions people post. A part of this is including the answer in your post, [instead of simply providing a link to another page that might answer the question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers/8259#8259). Please edit your answer to include the actual solution to the posted question. Refer to [How to reference material written by others](https://superuser.com/help/referencing) for help.

Answer (score -1):

I had this, turning off use hardware acceleration has fixed it (settings/advanced).

Comment: How did you do that exactly? Explain how someone would go about turning that off please and that'd be more helpful potentially.